# finding percentages between several numbers

Tags: arithmetic

My question: if i had an account that yielded $\$60$ in interest annually and another that yielded $\$500$ annually, what percentage better did the second account perform? Is it 830%

60 • X% = 500

X% = 500/60

X% = 8.3

830%

60 • 8.3 = 498

Comment: I think that you need to know the account balances before and after...  The \$500 yield might only be due to $1$% on $50000$ whereas the \$$60$ might be due to $10$% on $600$...

Comment: @abiessu While true in the real world, this reads like a textbook problem. The textbook either assumes the balances started equal or just ignores that piece of information all together.

Comment: the balance of each account started out as the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{500}{60} \neq 8.3$ so the answer is not $830\%$.

hardmath brings up a good point in the comments. Percentage better should be read as a percent increase. In which case it should be $60*(X+100)\%=500$ so that you get $733\frac{1}{3}\%$ better.

Comment: I'm doubtful that the setup is correct.  Suppose the amounts of interest earned were the same.  Would we then say (of each) that it did 100% *better* than the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking at raw dollar amounts, then the one that earned $\$500$ performed better than the one that earned $\$60.$

But as far as rate of return, the question itself doesn't give you enough information.  If the account that earned $\$60$ had $\$120$ to begin with, that's a $50\%$ return.  If the account that earned $\$500$ had $\$10000$ to begin with, that's only a $5\%$ return.

Now, if you *assume* that the amounts in each account are the same -- as you did -- then the one account did $500/60 \approx 833\%$ of the return of the other.